# "took a bath" or "have taken a bath"

Tags: difference, past-tense, usage

Which sentence is correct (if not both) and what is the difference between them?

1. I just took a bath. [moments ago]
2. I've just taken a bath.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.
"I've just taken a bath" is only adding the word "have" into the sentence.

Comment: But doesn't the emphasis go on to different facts? I am not a native English speaker and I am just asking this out of wondering. For instance, the sentence A can emphasize the action of taking a bath is done and the sentence B might emphasize the timing of finishing taking a bath is just now.

Comment: @SmartHumanism - I don't really see much of a difference in emphasis. Perhaps #2 sounds a bit more formal, but I agree with this answer in that they pretty much mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

In my idiolect (and that of many older British speakers) I would not use the simple past with "just", so I would only ever say "I have just taken"*  But the form "I just took" was common in American English when I was young, and has now become more common in British as well.

But among those who would use either, I don't think there is any difference in meaning.

*On a separate matter, the British idiom is "have a bath" rather than take a bath", so I would say "I have just had a bath" rather than either of your two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> I have taken a bath

refers to the fact that I have just completed the action of bathing.

> I took a bath

refers to the fact that I have completed the action of bathing some time ago.